# Clojure's "apply" function on strings

Tags: string, clojure

```
clojure.core/apply
([f args] [f x args] [f x y args] [f x y z args] [f a b c d & args])
  Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending intervening arguments to args.

user=> (apply str (reverse "racecar"))
"racecar"
user=> (str (reverse "racecar"))
"(\\r \\a \\c \\e \\c \\a \\r)"
```

I don't understand how this behavior is consistent with the docs. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. I'm assuming you're confused about the return type of `reverse`.

The `reverse` function returns a *sequence*, not a string. If you call reverse on a string, it treats it as a sequence of characters, and thus returns a reversed sequence of characters.

The `apply` function allows you to take a *sequence* of arguments and "unpack" them so you can pass them directly to a function as positional arguments. For example, `(apply f [a b c])` is equivalent to `(f a b c)`.

As I already mentioned, Clojure considers strings to be sequences of characers; therefore, `(apply str "racecar")` is the same as `(apply str '(\r \a \c \e \c \a \r))`, which is the same as `(str \r \a \c \e \c \a \r)`. So, when you call `apply str` on that sequence of characters, it concatenates all the characters together into a new string—and that's exactly what I would expect based on the documentation.

If you just want to reverse a string without needing to `apply str` to get a string result, you should use `clojure.string/reverse` instead of `clojure.core/reverse`:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.string :as str])
nil
user=> (str/reverse "hello")
"olleh"
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I convert from Seq => String in this case? `(filter #(and (>= (int %) 65) (<= (int %) 90)) "HeLlO, WoRlD!")`. I've tried using `apply str` but it's not working. Are there any other options?

Comment: @Chris - `(apply str (filter #(and (>= (int %) 65) (<= (int %) 90)) "HeLlO, WoRlD!"))` results in `"HLOWRD"` for me. What makes you say it doesn't work?

Comment: @Chris - FYI, one of the beauties of using prefix notation in Lisps is that functions like `<=` aren't forced to be binary. You can take advantage of that fact to simplify your filter function: `#(<= 65 (int %) 90)`. Of course, it would probably be even simpler and clearer this way: `#(Character/isUpperCase %)`. Note that Java methods aren't Clojure functions, so you you still have to wrap the call to `Character/isUpperCase` in a function.

Comment: @Chris - Just thought of another way to do this: `(clojure.string/replace "HeLlO, WoRlD!" #"[^A-Z]" "")`. That's equivalent to this Java method call: `(.replaceAll "HeLlO, WoRlD!" "[^A-Z]" "")`. If you're familiar with regular expressions, then this seems like the best solution to me.